# How To insert str_replace in single_post_title?

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

How do I insert the function `str_replace` in `single_post_title` ?

`<a class="tbutton large" href="http://domain.com/mp3/<?php single_post_title($str_replace =' ','+',''); ?>.html"><span> DOWNLOAD </span></a>`

But it is not working

Example :

Post Title Input Value:

`WIZ KHALIFA – COWBOY (OFFICIAL AUDIO)`

With `str_replace`, I wish to create a url like this:

`http://domain.com/mp3/wiz-khalifa-cowboy-official-audio.html`

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you use the post slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `str_replace()` on `single_post_title()` because it echoes the value instead of returning it.

You should use `get_the_title()` to get the title and use `sanitize_title()` to convert it into the format you want.

```
<?php

$title = get_the_title();
$download = "http://domain.com/mp3/" . sanitize_title($title) . ".html";

?>

<a href="<?php echo $download; ?>">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ sign from the start of str_replace to begin with

```
$input = "WIZ KHALIFA – COWBOY (OFFICIAL AUDIO";

<a class="tbutton large" href="http://domain.com/mp3/<?php single_post_title(str_replace(" ", "-", "$input")); ?>.html"><span> DOWNLOAD </span></a>
```

See the below for more help:

[str_replace](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)